# Ubuntu installation detects only Windows10 recovery partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, system-installation, windows-10

I have a windows 10 OS on a Lenovo z50-70 laptop. It has a 1 TB HDD. The windows partition is set as C drive with 889 GB space. The laptop manufacturer set a D drive with remaining 25 GB as recovery partition. The C drive has about 700GB free space (refreshed my PC recently).
[My Disk partitions as seen on Windows10 Disk Management Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A2Ta.png)

I was trying to setup a dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS. I had followed the installation steps as given on Ubuntu website and also other guides found during google search. I am able to boot into a USB live session. I am able to test the compatibility of my system. It seems good.

I proceed to install Ubuntu and select the 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager' option as Ubuntu installer has detected my windows 10 os.

But, in the next step, the installer doesn't detect and display my C drive which has enough free space. It seems to detect only the D drive (the recovery partition created by laptop manufacturer) which has only about 17 GB free space. [The disk partition/Space as shown during Ubuntu installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVvp8.png)

Could anyone please let me know how I can resolve this issue? Is there a way to get Ubuntu installer to detect the space on C drive for partitioning it during installation? Or is there a separate workflow to install dual boot setup when there is a recovery partition present?

Comment: As a general hint: Deactivate "Fast Startup" mode in Windows and you should mount ntfs volumes in read-only mode in Linux/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the `advanced partitioning tool` highlighted in blue. It is literally written that 6 smaller partitions are hidden. Clicking it will show you all the partitions on the disk. Also it is better to create partition within windows and seperate out required amount of space for installing ubuntu. This way you won't mess up windows while installing `ubuntu`

Comment: Thanks Fahad. If we create partition within windows and separate out required amount of space as un-allocated space, would Ubuntu installer recognize it when opting for 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager'. Or do we have to select 'Something Else' and manually allocate the free space to Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Ubuntu installer will detect the free space. Ubuntu installer didn't show you the windows partiton upfront because you may mess it up.